# How to run conditional subqueries in Kusto

Tags: kql

Any idea if we can run different subqueries based on `iff` or `case` in Kusto. For example like this:

```
let logtype = 0;//1

let query1 = stormEvents1
| project Message 
| take 1;

let query2 = stormEvents2
| project Message 
| take 1;
iff(logtype == 0, query1, query2); // Syntax error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, there are no control flow statements in KQL.
That said, we can acheive similar behavior using *union*.

```
let logtype = 0;//1
let query1 = StormEvents
| project Source 
| take 1;
let query2 = StormEvents
| project EventType 
| take 1;
union (query1 | where logtype == 0)
     ,(query2 | where logtype == 1)
```

| Source | EventType |
| --- | --- |
| Trained Spotter |  |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tJLVHIyU8vqSxIVbBVMLDW1zfk5coBChaWphZVGgLFgkvyi3Jdy1LzSop5uWoUCorys1KTSxSC80uLklMVQEIlidmpCobWSPqMcOsDi4SArEPRWpqXmZ%20noAG1tUahPCO1KBXhMqDTNHm5FEBARwNqBRZFhpoAATNm69AAAAA=)